# greensock tween find end rotation of bezier curve

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, gsap

Let me tell you a scenario which am facing right now , I have a movieclip which will move along the bezier curve and a button which will start the play(movie clip will move along the curve) and bezier points , am using greensock which have an autorotate option where you will rotate the movie clip along the path.

so i need to know what rotation will the movieclip will be at the end of play , because when auto rotate is enabled my rotation at start time will be 0 but by the end time of the play what will it be ???? I need to know that value before the tween happens , please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, of course, math that you could do to figure it all out, but it's probably easier to just let the tween handle it and simply jump to the end, read the value, and rewind again. No need to create a separate tween that lasts 0.0001 seconds and wait for an onComplete or anything like that - just use the original tween:

```
var tween:TweenMax = TweenMax.to(...); //your bezier tween
tween.progress(1); //jump to the end
var endRotation:Number = mc.rotation; //read the final rotation
tween.progress(0); //rewind back to the beginning
```

Comment: Sweet! Didn't know about the progress method, thanks for that!

Comment: tried this code and got this error
 
`1061: Call to a possibly undefined method progress through a reference with static type com.greensock:TweenLite.`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that in the ActionScript version progress() is TweenMax-only. Either use that or leverage the time() method like tween.time(tween.duration()); to skip to the end and tween.time(0); to rewind.

Answer (score 1):

There is sure some mathematical way to calculate this but then you would basically need to rewrite the whole bezier movement logic.

A quick and dirty way would be to set your movieclip alpha to 0 at first (or create a new empty sprite) and let the same bezier movement run within lets say 0.0001 second. In onComplete check the final movieclip rotation and start the actual tweening. I'ts kind of hacky but it will work :)

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about the same , but as i have a lot of mc's i thought it might slow down my performance , still i will use this as a back up plan , thanks for that.